# Python script exits with exit code 255 despite try-except block

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I am trying to build some exception handling into my Script before sending it out to users trial. To achieve this I'm trying to run `try-except` blocks to catch errors where I think they're likely to occur.

For example, the code uses an API to interact with another piece of software. This software relies on a hardware licence (USB dongle) to be installed in teh computer, otherwise the software cannot be accessed by Python and the script exits with Exit Code 255. Code example below.

```
    code-to-activate-licence
except Exception as e:
     warn-user-of-error
```

I would expect the `try-except` block to pick up the exit code and execute the `except` portion of the code. However, I assume that as the attempt to activate the licence does not seem to raise an error but instead gives a non-zero exit code it doesn't seem to be caught by the `try-except` block. Is there a way to catch this exit code before it actually exits the script?

Comment: Are you interacting with the API directly or are you importing some library to access the API?

Comment: It seems that the code crashes.

Comment: As per the [exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy), maybe try catching`SystemExit`?

Comment: @GiraffeMan91 I'm interacting with it through a library that is imported. As per your suggestion below, I've tried specifying ```SystemExit``` instead ```Exception``` but it ends the same (the script exits with an exit code of 255).

Comment: Can you tell me the library and function you are using?

Comment: Sure, but it's quite obscure. I'm using the Python API for DigSILENT PowerFactory. The call that is causing the error is from the powerfactory module,  powerfactory.GetApplication().

Comment: I have contacted the library providers and they have confirmed that, at the time of the issue, there was no way to wrap the activation attempt in a try loop without throwing an error. The issue was with the library and not with the code I was trying to implement.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `except Exception as e:` however the library is calling `sys.exit()` which raises a `SystemExit` which is of type `BaseException` rather than a standard `Exception`. `Exception` encompasses all non-system-exiting exceptions.

You need to explicitly catch `SystemExit` in order to interrupt it.

From the [[docs]](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit):

> **exception SystemExit**
>
> > This exception is raised by the sys.exit() function. It inherits from BaseException instead of Exception so that it is not accidentally caught by code that catches Exception.
>
> **exception Exception**
>
> > All built-in, non-system-exiting exceptions are derived from this class. All user-defined exceptions should also be derived from this class.

In code it would look something like:

```py
try:
    somecode()
except Exception as e:
    do_something_with_exception(e)
except SystemExit as x:
    do_something_not_exit(x)
```